# Jquery datepicker in master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker, master-pages

I know there is so many similar question already been asked but none of them solved my problem. I tried so many times but the datepicker still not work.

So in my master page

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head/>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In my content Page(head section inside asp content place holder 1)

```
     // i tried this 4 way but still not work
     // $("[id$=txtStart]")
     // $("input[id$='date2']").datepicker(); 
     <%--<%=txtStart.ClientID%>--%>
    <%-- $("#<%=txtStart.ClientID %>")--%>

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('[id$=txtStart]').datepicker({
             minDate: 0,
             dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             numberOfMonths: 2,
             onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                 var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
                 min.setDate(min.getDate() + 1);
                 $('[id$=txtEnd]').datepicker('option', 'minDate', min); // Set other min, default to today

             }
         });

  //another datepicker same as above
         $('[id$=txtEnd]').datepicker({
            .....
             }
         });


     });
```

this is my control

```
   <td class="auto-style3"><asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server" > </asp:TextBox>
   <td class="auto-style3"><asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server" > </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: $("#"+<%=txtStart.ClientID%>).datepicker({})  try this.

Comment: did you look at the example at [jQuery UI page](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) ? I test it and it's exactly what you need

Comment: @ParthTrivedi got syntax error

Comment: can you show me? which error

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i alrdy fix the syntax error, but the datepicker still not working

Comment: Ok is it binding correctly?

Comment: Can you give current code?after syntax error fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97763/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-xiao-cii-onn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=txtStart.ClientID%>").datepicker({
             minDate: 0,
             dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             numberOfMonths: 2,
             onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                 var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Get selected date
                 min.setDate(min.getDate() + 1);
                 $("#<%=txtEnd.ClientID%>").datepicker('option', 'minDate', min); // Set other min, default to today

             }
         });

     });
```

Comment: you can use `$("[id$=txtStart]")` as a [jQuery Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) ... no wrong there, his error is the range...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and works fine with this code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[id$=txtStart]").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $("[id$=txtEnd]").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        from <asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server"/> to <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server"/>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Thought **I would suggest [another datepicker range](https://github.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker)**.

then your code would be:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var dtStart = $('[id$=txtStart]'),
            dtEnd = $('[id$=txtEnd]');

        $('[id$=txtStart]').dateRangePicker(
        {
            separator: ' to ',
            getValue: function() {
                if (dtStart.val() && dtEnd.val())
                    return dtStart.val() + ' to ' + dtEnd.val();
                else
                    return '';
            },
            setValue: function(s, s1, s2) {
                dtStart.val(s1);
                dtEnd.val(s2);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and your master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/daterangepicker.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/jquery.daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: the script must put inside asp ContentPlaceHolderID="head"?

Comment: No, but I always use to `ContentPlaceholder` 's, one for content and other for script's or css that would go between the `<head>` tags